# Prepare LimeSurvey output with sql for Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, unpivot, limesurvey

I’m working with Lime Survey and ultimately want to use Crystal Reports for my final output, and am looking for help with the intervening steps. I have one row per response record, with 100+ questions, which are split into several sections. The output looks like a cross-tab with a column per question, but I the data needs to be unpivoted before I can work with it in Crystal Reports.

Depending on the survey, there might be 4 sections or there could be as many as 15. So, is there a way to do this dynamically with sql, based on the number of sections?

To illustrate – in Excel the output from Lime Survey looks like this

```
ID  Subject Relationship    1Section    1SQuestion1 1SQuestion2 2Section    2SQuestion1 2SQuestion2
1   John    Boss            1Section    2           4           2Section    3           4
2   John    Peer            1Section    4           3           2Section    2           5
3   Sally   Boss            1Section    3           3           2Section    4           5
4   Sally   Peer            1Section    5           6           2Section    1           3
```

Here’s what I ultimately need it to look like

```
ID  Subject Relationship    1Section    Col5            Col6
1   John    Boss            1Section    1SQuestion1     2
1   John    Boss            1Section    1SQuestion2     4
2   John    Peer            1Section    1SQuestion1     4
2   John    Peer            1Section    1SQuestion2     3
3   Sally   Boss            1Section    1SQuestion1     3
3   Sally   Boss            1Section    1SQuestion2     3
4   Sally   Peer            1Section    1SQuestion1     5
4   Sally   Peer            1Section    1SQuestion2     6
1   John    Boss            2Section    2SQuestion1     3
1   John    Boss            2Section    2SQuestion2     4
2   John    Peer            2Section    2SQuestion1     2
2   John    Peer            2Section    2SQuestion2     5
3   Sally   Boss            2Section    2SQuestion1     4
3   Sally   Boss            2Section    2SQuestion2     5
4   Sally   Peer            2Section    2SQuestion1     1
4   Sally   Peer            2Section    2SQuestion2     3
```

Thanks

Comment: Finally I think what you really need in that final survey Data Table that you send to Crystal: an incremental primary key, response ID #, subject name, relationship name, section #, question #, answer #. Optionally, you could send it the survey ID, too, and then you can always store as many surveys and responses as you need in that one Data Table.

Comment: Okay after playing around with the Demo of Lime Survey, I understand a little more, now. So, do you not have access to the database at all and will have to rely on these Excel files?

Comment: I do have access to database, do you have some insight there?.  Thanks

Comment: @Tim What is the database behind this data?

Comment: On my web host were LimeSurvey is installed I am using **MySQL database** (Is this what you are asking? the database was made with MySQL Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform this data transformation in sql, then you can use a `UNION ALL` query:

```
select id, subject, relationship, `1Section`, '1sQuestion1' col5, `1sQuestion1` col6
from yourtable
union all
select id, subject, relationship, `1Section`, '1sQuestion2' col5, `1sQuestion2` col6
from yourtable
union all
select id, subject, relationship, `2Section`, '2sQuestion1' col5, `2sQuestion1` col6
from yourtable
union all
select id, subject, relationship, `2Section`, '2sQuestion2' col5, `2sQuestion2` col6
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1385c/1). Which gives the result:

```
| ID | SUBJECT | RELATIONSHIP | 1SECTION |        COL5 | COL6 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    John |         Boss | 1Section | 1sQuestion1 |    2 |
|  2 |    John |         Peer | 1Section | 1sQuestion1 |    4 |
|  3 |   Sally |         Boss | 1Section | 1sQuestion1 |    3 |
|  4 |   Sally |         Peer | 1Section | 1sQuestion1 |    5 |
|  1 |    John |         Boss | 1Section | 1sQuestion2 |    4 |
|  2 |    John |         Peer | 1Section | 1sQuestion2 |    3 |
|  3 |   Sally |         Boss | 1Section | 1sQuestion2 |    3 |
|  4 |   Sally |         Peer | 1Section | 1sQuestion2 |    6 |
|  1 |    John |         Boss | 2Section | 2sQuestion1 |    3 |
|  2 |    John |         Peer | 2Section | 2sQuestion1 |    2 |
|  3 |   Sally |         Boss | 2Section | 2sQuestion1 |    4 |
|  4 |   Sally |         Peer | 2Section | 2sQuestion1 |    1 |
|  1 |    John |         Boss | 2Section | 2sQuestion2 |    4 |
|  2 |    John |         Peer | 2Section | 2sQuestion2 |    5 |
|  3 |   Sally |         Boss | 2Section | 2sQuestion2 |    5 |
|  4 |   Sally |         Peer | 2Section | 2sQuestion2 |    3 |
```

Comment: Hello bluefeet, thank you for your time and code it is much appriciated.

Comment: bluefeet I have another question.  Say instead I wanted to make the output as two tables; one table is the data of 1Section and the second table is the data of 2Section.  I have played some with sqlfiddle but my knowledge of sql is very limited.

Comment: @Tim you can do the same thing if the data is in different tables. See this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0aff/1